# Parsing JSON Array with Ruby and SmarterCSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I am pretty new to ruby, and I am trying to parse an array using smarter_csv.

smarter CSV outputs an array that looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "phone": "(206) 745-2185",
        "neighborhood": "Belltown",
        "city": "Seattle",
        "state": "WA"
    },
    {
        "phone": "(206) 728-6069",
        "neighborhood": "Belltown",
        "city": "Seattle",
        "state": "WA"
    },
    {
        "phone": "(206) 441-5449",
        "neighborhood": "Belltown",
        "city": "Seattle",
        "state": "WA"
    }
]
```

This is what the code looks like, but I'm having a difficult time getting things to work:

```
require 'smarter_csv'
json = render json: SmarterCSV.process('public/cities.csv')
json.each do |item|
  puts item
end
```

I am trying to store the phone number.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `json`. Just access the phone number using `item[:phone]`.

```
require 'smarter_csv'
items= SmarterCSV.process('public/cities.csv')
items.each do |item|
  puts item[:phone]
end
```

If you want to get an array of phone numbers:

```
require 'smarter_csv'
items = SmarterCSV.process('public/cities.csv')
phone_numbers = items.map { |item| item[:phone] }
```